# Careers links in mega menu

Tags: layout, information-architecture, mega-menu

I am designing a corporate website career page. Should I use a mega menu for the career page? Here are some of the items related to the career page:

1. Who we are!
2. What we do?
3. Life at Our Company!
4. Reasons to join us?

   - compensation
   - benefits
   - work/life

Answer (score 1):

Welcome Naveed to UXStackExchange.

I think a megamenu is a bit of an overkill with the options you are currently listing.

Here is [an article from NN/G](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/mega-menus-work-well/) with a quote

> Mega menus (sometimes spelled “megamenus”) are a type of expandable
> menu in which many choices are displayed in a two-dimensional dropdown
> layout. **They are an excellent design choice for accommodating a large
> number of options or for revealing lower-level site pages at a glance.**

Now, if you plan on adding more options in the future. Like top-level job categories or more resources, then it might indeed be a good idea to go for a mega menu and make it a tad future-proof.

Another thing to consider is the overall aesthetic of your website and what type of users you expect to visit. Will a mega menu perhaps be useful in other aspects of your website? Then you could implement it as a common design/aesthetic component.

Or, will your users be mostly visiting via mobile? Then maybe again a megamenu can work instead of a fiddly dropdown.

Whatever you choose consider the options you are currently offering, the ones you will offer in the future, and the behaviour you expect from your users. If in doubt, it sounds like the perfect excuse for some A/B testing ;)

Answer (score 0):

This decision could arrive after looking at information architecture of the whole website. But, looking at the content you plan to put, it appears that can come on single page instead of links in mega menu

Comment: thank you @Sujit Devkar for you quick response, so mega menu issue for any specific page?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can only if you have multiple list of job or multiple jobs in different categories then you can show categories in individual columns.